# Clear note from cells based on conditional formatting color

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google Sheet script that clears all notes in a sheet that has a trigger to run daily. I really want it to just “clear notes” in cells that are conditionally formatted green that day. As background info, the notes are automatically added to various cells by an add-on but when the cell turns green again, I want the note attached to that cell to be cleared. Is this possible? I've provided the code that I have so far but get confused with the array getRange part. Thank you!

```
function cleargreens() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");

  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();  //2D array of sheet1 cell values
  var bg;

  for(var i=1; i<data1.length; i++)
  {
    bg = sheet1.getRange(i+1, 2).getBackground();
    if(bg == "#b7e1cd") //this is the conditional green color code
    {
      sheet1.getRange(i+1, 3).clearNote();
    }
```

[My spreadsheet, although the colors I will be searching for will only be in columns E to H](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpFLT.jpg)

Comment: Yes - it's possible.

Comment: Good to know, at least, haha. I have updated the question with what code I have thus far. Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Comment: Great - what's not working with this code? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No error messages or issues when debugged. The cells with that color code just do not have notes removed. I don't know that the getRange or "var i=" part is correct. Thank you!

Comment: Ok - so you're looking to loop through a few different columns. Do all of them need to be set to the same background colour for the note to clear or only one?

Comment: Thanks, Ross! Yes, correct, just looping through those few columns looking for cells that contain that color and clearing the note (if one exists). Just that one green color code which I obtained from the log.

Comment: Use batch methods i.e. `getDataRange().getBackgrounds()`, store the R1C1 references of cells to modify based on that 0-index array of arrays, and then use [`Rangelist#clearNote`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#clearNote()) to get them all. Should take only a handful of seconds even for 2k+ formatted cells.

Comment: Thank you, tehhowch! I'll look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your cells can potentially have notes which need to be removed when the background color is green - then you need to implement a nested loop, which iterates through both rows AND columns:

```
function cleargreens() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Overview");

  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();  //2D array of sheet1 cell values
  var bg;
//iterates through rows
  for(var i=1; i<data1.length; i++)
  {
//iterates through columns    
    for(var j=1; j<data1[0].length; j++)
    {
      var cell=sheet1.getRange(i+1, j);
      bg = cell.getBackground();
      if(bg == "#b7e1cd") //this is the conditional green color code
      {
        cell.clearNote();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As for your confusion, be aware that a range is a 2-D array with a row and column index.